# CakePHP, JQuery .load a controller function

Tags: jquery, cakephp, controller, load

I'm having a little trouble getting Jquery to play nice with cakephp and I'm not really sure what the problem is.

view file, View/Members/index.ctp

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#place").click(function(event){
      $("#place").load('/member/jax', function(){
        alert("load successful");
      });
    });

  });

</script>
<div id="place"></div>
```

Controller file Controller/MembersController

```
public function jax() {
  echo "<p>TESTTHIS</p>";
  $this->layout='ajax';
  $this->render('/Elements/test');
}
```

and for completeness

Test element /View/Elements/test.ctp

```
<b>test element</b>
```

When I click on the div I get the "load successful" popup, but I do not get the "

TESTTHIS

that I expect the controller to print out, nor do I get the "**test element**" from the render.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with following:

```
$("#place").load('/members/jax',...
```

Conventionally controller in CakePHP call with plural name. So, I think it should `members` not `member`.

Comment: Goshdarnit. I've spent so long hacking and revising the code that a simple typo tripped me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the complete controller with view then print the URL of your controller and view in .load() through PHP

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The original problem was a typo in the code (as pointed out by the accepted answer).